# How to conditionally include images in an IOS project - so I can have multiple occurance of same image?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios5

In my IOS project I have an image (call it x.png)
for certain cases I copy into the projects x.png from one folder, then under different conditions I copy from another folder. Then I build the project so I end up with 2 versions of the project each with its own version of the image.

Can I automate this phase? i.e If some flag is set the project will take the file from one place, otherwise take it from the other place?

Comment: You can create your own build phases for resources copying, not sure which kind of rule you would use there.

Comment: thanks, but how do I tell the dev. env. which build phase to use? Tried to define a new target - did not work.  I end up having twice as much resources then needed + disgusting code to switch images in onViewLoad

Comment: You can use the same build phase, the trick is to select the directory to copy files from, e.g. with script phase you can read special configuration file. In my opinion it would be great to use environment variables but I'm not sure what would be the best case to set them in this case.

Comment: thanks. Do you know of any example or concrete search phase for google?

Comment: `ditto ./images1/ "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH"` will copy files from images1 folder into the main bundle during build.